# Adicionar mensagem na resposta do OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth2, oauth

Criei um web api com validação por tokens que funciona corretamente, meu problema é:
Gostaria de colocar uma mensagem após as informações obrigatórias, deixo em anexo uma imagem exemplo(Gostaria de adicionar aquele "validado") e também meu código.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Grato!

```
namespace BRWAdmPanel.Services

public class ProviderDeTokensDeAcesso : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        if (UserSecurity.Login(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
            context.Validated(identity);

        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("acesso inválido", "As credenciais do usuário não conferem....");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Adicionando outras partes do código para melhor entendimento:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //config da webapi
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //config de rota
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        //ativando CORS
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        //ativando a geração de token
        AtivarGeracaoTokenAcesso(app);
        //ativando webapi
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
    private void AtivarGeracaoTokenAcesso(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var opcoesConfiguracaoToken = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new ProviderDeTokensDeAcesso()
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(opcoesConfiguracaoToken);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Ultima parte:

```
 public static bool Login(string login, string password)
    {

        MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        // Converter a String para array de bytes, que é como a biblioteca trabalha.
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

        // Cria-se um StringBuilder para recompôr a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop para formatar cada byte como uma String em hexadecimal
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        using (BRWAdmPanelEntities entities = new BRWAdmPanelEntities())
        {
            password = sBuilder.ToString();
            return entities.OHEM.Any(user =>
           user.pager.Equals(login, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
           && user.U_BRWPassword == password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem que ser com colocado na parte do código referente a construção do token que não é esse código pelo menos até onde eu sei é no retorno desses dados. Cadê todo o código?

Comment: Bom dia Virgilio, obrigado por responder, vou atualizar com todo o código de geração do token, como sou iniciante não compreendi muito bem onde fica essa parte de construção mas espero que consiga te mandar os corretos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar a alteração que você precisa é necessário estar utilizando o método `TokenEndpointResponse` junto de `context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("chave", "valor");

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

No exemplo acima a variável `context` possui a propriedade `Identity`, que dentro dela possui uma lista de claims, então você pode estar acessando ela para fazer algo como buscar um dado através do id armazenado dentro da claims.

`context.Identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "sub").Value`

No exemplo acima você consegue pegar o valor armazenado dentro da claim sub.

Comment: Perfeito! funcionou da maneira que eu queria, muito obrigado!